# Why not toggle classes in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, addclass, toggleclass

I created a little sketch to testing my knowledge. I would like to change classes by click on td elements.

I added a basic class and after i'd change with toggleClass(). Unfortunately doesn't works.

```
$( function() {
    $('td').addClass("grey-cell");

    $('td').click( function() {
        if($(this).hasClass("grey-cell"))
            $(this).toggleClass("red-cell");
        if($(this).hasClass("red-cell"))
            $(this).toggleClass("blue-cell");
        if($(this).hasClass("blue-cell"))
            $(this).toggleClass("green-cell");
        if($(this).hasClass("green-cell"))
            $(this).toggleClass("grey-cell");
    });
});
```

[code sketch](https://jsfiddle.net/ov3z0xh3/1/)

Comment: your code would lastly return you with grey-cell class, because you need to use return false; after each if condition, or use if, elseif and else.. for proper results.. thanks..

Comment: check the answer of T.J. Crowder and this fiddle as well https://jsfiddle.net/ov3z0xh3/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's follow it through logically:

```
$(function() {
    $('td').addClass("grey-cell");

    $('td').click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("grey-cell"))
            $(this).toggleClass("red-cell");
        if ($(this).hasClass("red-cell"))
            $(this).toggleClass("blue-cell");
        if ($(this).hasClass("blue-cell"))
            $(this).toggleClass("green-cell");
        if ($(this).hasClass("green-cell"))
            $(this).toggleClass("grey-cell");
    });
});
```

When you click a cell, it will have `grey-cell`, so you toggle `red-cell` on. Then, on the next line, you see if it has `red-cell` (it will) and if so you toggle `blue-cell` on. Then you do the same with blue/green, then `green/grey`.

So after the first click, the `td` has `red-cell blue-cell green-cell` and doesn't have `grey-cell`.

My guess is you meant to

A) Use `else` so only one path was followed, and

B) Turn off the previous class it has

E.g.:

```
$(function() {
  $('td').addClass("grey-cell");

  $('td').click(function() {
    var td = $(this);
    if (td.hasClass("grey-cell")) {
      td.toggleClass("grey-cell red-cell");
    } else if (td.hasClass("red-cell")) {
      td.toggleClass("red-cell blue-cell");
    } else if (td.hasClass("blue-cell")) {
      td.toggleClass("blue-cell green-cell");
    } else if (td.hasClass("green-cell")) {
      td.toggleClass("green-cell grey-cell");
    }
  });
});
```

Note how when we know it has (say) `grey-cell`, we include `grey-cell` in the `toggleClass` so we remove it when adding `red-cell`. And so on.

```js
$(function() {
  $('td').addClass("grey-cell");

  $('td').click(function() {
    var td = $(this);
    if (td.hasClass("grey-cell")) {
      td.toggleClass("grey-cell red-cell");
    } else if (td.hasClass("red-cell")) {
      td.toggleClass("red-cell blue-cell");
    } else if (td.hasClass("blue-cell")) {
      td.toggleClass("blue-cell green-cell");
    } else if (td.hasClass("green-cell")) {
      td.toggleClass("green-cell grey-cell");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.grey-cell {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
.red-cell {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
.blue-cell {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
.green-cell {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Click me</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without using complex `if else`. Make an array of class in your required sequence. Then on click of `td` change class according to the sequence of array. If you reached at the last item of array then go back to first.

```
$(function() {
    $('td').addClass("grey-cell");
    var classes = ['grey-cell', 'red-cell', 'blue-cell', 'green-cell'];
    var total = classes.length;

    $('td').click(function () {
        var cls = $(this).attr('class');

        //if you have other classes then take last class
        //var arr = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
        //var cls = arr[arr.length];

        var index = classes.indexOf(cls);
        index = (index + 1) % total;

        $(this).removeClass(cls).addClass(classes[index]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Good idea, but best to check not just with `indexOf`, since (say) a `colored-cell` class would confuse that check. Also, just FYI, there's an `index` rollover trick you can use: `index = (index + 1) % classes.length;`